# How to define a `separator` tag in play-1.x without modifing play's source code

Tags: tags, playframework-1.x

I want to define a tag `separator` tag, which inside a `list` tag, can add separator between items.

The sample code is:

```
List<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();
users.add("Jeff");
users.add("Mike");

#{list users, as: 'user'}
    #{separator ' + ' /}
    <span>${user}</span>
#{/list}
```

If I don't use the `separator` tag, the code will be:

```
#{list users, as: 'user'}
    ${user_isFirst ? '' : ' + '}
    <span>${user}</span>
#{/list}
```

The generated html code will be:

```
<span>Jeff</span> + <span>Mike</span>
```

I tried defined a `fastTag`:

```
public static void _separator(Map<?, ?> args, Closure body, PrintWriter out, GroovyTemplate.ExecutableTemplate template, int fromLine) {
    Object value = args.get("arg");

    // TODO how to get the value of `as` defined in parent `list` tag?

    out.print(value);
}
```

But the problem is I can't get the value of `as` defined in `list` tag (which is `user`) in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom list tag in groovy like this

```
#{list items:_arg, as:'tmp'}

    %{
            attrs = [:]
            attrs.put(_as, tmp)
    }%

    #{ifnot tmp_isFirst}${_sep}#{/ifnot}
    #{doBody vars:attrs /}

#{/list}
```

and use it like this

```
#{myList users, as:'user', sep:','}
    ${user}
#{/myList}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should trace into your FastTag implementation.  I think you'll see all the variables in scope inside the args map.  This is from memory - so, sorry if not.

That said, I think it might be simpler if you copy the Java code for #{list} and add a new parameter,  like

```
#{list users, as: 'user', separator: '+' }
```

and handle the logic in there.  It seems a bit cleaner too from a design point of view - if it is a separator, how come you can put it anywhere you like in the code (and why not put it in twice!).

A final option is to look at Groovy or Java collection operators. http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html

Comment: `list` tag is in "GroovyInlineTags" file, there is no way to add `separator` without modifying the source code: https://github.com/freewind/replay/blob/master/framework/src/play/templates/GroovyInlineTags.java#L74

Comment: seb's answer is great - i'd go with that.  it's a different way to implement your own #{list} using the Play .tag feature